# Unity 2D jumping with Rigidbody velocity doesn't feel good

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I'm using the classic way to make a character jump by changing it's Rigidbody's velocity, code in the next image : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAOub.png)

The problem is that sometimes when I hit the ground, I have to wait a few frames before being able jump, it's not that much reactive. And I also want to know if it's ok to change the Rigidbody's velocity in the Update method, if not then how can I link the inputs in the Update with the physics in the FixedUpdate.
What can i do to make the jump instant when the player reaches the ground ? making the ground check radius bigger doesn't solve it. And also is it possible to give the player some kind of margin, save the player's jump input a few frames before hitting the ground but wait until he hit the ground to actually do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `isGrounded` variable is changing later. Since `FixedUpdate` is calling fewer times unlike the `Update`, you get this problem. Try to move `isGrounded` variable setting to the `Update` method, let it be the first line in the `Update`.

Continues physics (add force for more than just one frame etc) should be done in the `FixedUpdate`. However, firing physics functions only once - it can be in the `Update` method, no problems with that.

Comment: One way to handle grounded check is to add sensor trigger collider under the players feet then in the OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit methods simply add/remove colliders from a list. When list is empty it means player is not grounded. Just be sure to set it on different collision layer than the player and check that colliders only get added once to the list.